express-openapi-validator: Is it possible to read the openApi extensions
As a developer, I would like to add a custom extension to my api.yaml file, so that the application can use it for a generic operation.
We have created several micro-services using express-openapi-validator. We would like to add our own custom extension to the openApi file and then have the node.js application read that extension. The format would look something like:
/my-endpoint:
  get:
    operationId: processGetMyEndpoint
    x-eov-operation-handler: myController
    x-custom-extension: custom-value

Then, in the code:
function processGetMyEndpoint(req, res) {
  const customExtensionValue = getCustomExtension(req);

  // Code that uses that extension
}

Is that possible using https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-openapi-validator?
I have tried reading through the docs and the example file but could not find anything. Has anyone else added and retrieved a custom extension?

I found the answer, the schema information is available via req.openapi.schema. I can get the extension through that.

Mark an answer as the correct answer if this question was correctly answered by said answer! (Mark your answer as the correct answer)
